# Explode items to rows and convert dictionary to columns does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Following sampledata is given:

```
data = [
    {
        "name": "Sampleproject 1",
        "tasks": [
            {
                "order": 1,
                "description": "Do something 1",
                "status": "Done",
                "active": False
            },
            {
                "order": 3,
                "description": "Do something 3",
                "status": "Open",
                "active": False
            },
            {
                "order": 2,
                "description": "Do something 2",
                "status": "Open",
                "active": True
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Sampleproject 2",
        "tasks": [
            {
                "order": 1,
                "description": "Do something 1",
                "status": "Done",
                "active": False
            },
            {
                "order": 1,
                "description": "Do something 3",
                "status": "Open",
                "active": True
            },
            {
                "order": 1,
                "description": "Do something 2",
                "status": "Open",
                "active": True
            },
            {
                "order": 2,
                "description": "Do something 4",
                "status": "Open",
                "active": False
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I need to normalize this data for writing it to CSV file.
A single row for each task in tasks works well with *.explode()*. After this I have one column *tasks* with the task object. Next step is to convert this task object in single columns with *.apply(pd.Series)* but this does not work. I still get the full object as one column.

I found many similar cases and tutorials for this issue but nothing worked on my sample data.
I´m pretty sure the solution is easy, but where is the mistake I don´t see?

My code so far:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.explode("tasks")
df["tasks"].apply(pd.Series)
df.to_csv('testfile.csv', index=False)
```

The CSV content:

```
name,tasks
Sampleproject 1,"{'order': 1, 'description': 'Do something 1', 'status': 'Done', 'active': False}"
Sampleproject 1,"{'order': 3, 'description': 'Do something 3', 'status': 'Open', 'active': False}"
Sampleproject 1,"{'order': 2, 'description': 'Do something 2', 'status': 'Open', 'active': True}"
Sampleproject 2,"{'order': 1, 'description': 'Do something 1', 'status': 'Done', 'active': False}"
Sampleproject 2,"{'order': 1, 'description': 'Do something 3', 'status': 'Open', 'active': True}"
Sampleproject 2,"{'order': 1, 'description': 'Do something 2', 'status': 'Open', 'active': True}"
Sampleproject 2,"{'order': 2, 'description': 'Do something 4', 'status': 'Open', 'active': False}"
```

**EDIT:**

Required/Expected CSV output:

```
name,order,description,status,active
Sampleproject 1,1,'Do something 1','Done',False
Sampleproject 1,3,'Do something 3','Open',False
Sampleproject 1,2,'Do something 2','Open',True
Sampleproject 2,1,'Do something 1','Done',False
Sampleproject 2,1,'Do something 3','Open',True
Sampleproject 2,1,'Do something 2','Open',True
Sampleproject 2,2,'Do something 4','Open',False
```

Comment: What do you want the output to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to bind the exploded data as new columns to the original data.

```
pd.concat([
    df.drop(columns='tasks'),
    df.tasks.explode().apply(pd.Series)
], axis=1)
#               name  order     description status  active
# 0  Sampleproject 1      1  Do something 1   Done   False
# 0  Sampleproject 1      3  Do something 3   Open   False
# 0  Sampleproject 1      2  Do something 2   Open    True
# 1  Sampleproject 2      1  Do something 1   Done   False
# 1  Sampleproject 2      1  Do something 3   Open    True
# 1  Sampleproject 2      1  Do something 2   Open    True
# 1  Sampleproject 2      2  Do something 4   Open   False
```

Comment: I´m sorry, this is not the expected result (have added expected output to description). Maybe pd.Series is wrong

Comment: Silly me. I have updated my answer to add _all_ the columns.

Answer (score 1):

To handle your nested data, i'll normalize first the data before passing it to Pandas like this example:

```
def normalize(data): 
    for elm in data: 
        for k in elm.get('tasks', []): 
            k.update({'name': elm.get('name')}) 
            yield k

df = pd.dataFrame(normalize(data))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   order     description status  active             name
0      1  Do something 1   Done   False  Sampleproject 1
1      3  Do something 3   Open   False  Sampleproject 1
2      2  Do something 2   Open    True  Sampleproject 1
3      1  Do something 1   Done   False  Sampleproject 2
4      1  Do something 3   Open    True  Sampleproject 2
5      1  Do something 2   Open    True  Sampleproject 2
6      2  Do something 4   Open   False  Sampleproject 2
```

A bit of comparison:

```
In [1]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(normalize(data))                             
661 µs ± 7.15 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [2]: %timeit pd.concat([df.drop(columns='tasks'),df.tasks.explode().apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
4.53 ms ± 118 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

And like you can see, normalizing your data before passing to Pandas is a way faster than using `concat` + `explode` functions .